# what are registry settings to enable TCP on SQL Server 2005 and 2008?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, wmi

I want to programatically enable TCP connections on SQL Server. I believe we can achieve this by modifying registry entries and restarting SQL Server service. What registry should I edit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless you have a good reason for modifying the registry directly, I suggest you consider using `WMI`.  WMI will provide you with a more version agnostic implementation. WMI can be accessed through the [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.aspx) namespace.  You could have code that looks something like this.

```
public void EnableSqlServerTcp(string serverName, string instanceName)
{
    ManagementScope scope =
            new ManagementScope(@"\\" + serverName +
                                @"\root\Microsoft\SqlServer\ComputerManagement");
    ManagementClass sqlService =
            new ManagementClass(scope,
                                new ManagementPath("SqlService"), null);
    ManagementClass serverProtocol =
            new ManagementClass(scope,
                                new ManagementPath("ServerNetworkProtocol"), null);

    sqlService.Get();
    serverProtocol.Get();

    foreach (ManagementObject prot in serverProtocol.GetInstances())
    {
        prot.Get();
        if ((string)prot.GetPropertyValue("ProtocolName") == "Tcp" &&
            (string)prot.GetPropertyValue("InstanceName") == instanceName)
        {
            prot.InvokeMethod("SetEnable", null);
        }
    }

    uint sqlServerService = 1;
    uint sqlServiceStopped = 1;
    foreach (ManagementObject instance in sqlService.GetInstances())
    {
        if ((uint)instance.GetPropertyValue("SqlServiceType") == sqlServerService &&
            (string)instance.GetPropertyValue("ServiceName") == instanceName)
        {
            instance.Get();
            if ((uint)instance.GetPropertyValue("State") != sqlServiceStopped)
            {
                instance.InvokeMethod("StopService", null);
            }
            instance.InvokeMethod("StartService", null);
        }
    }
}
```

This code assumes a project reference to `System.Management.dll` and the following using statement:

```
using System.Management;
```

The [Sql Protocols](http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_protocols/default.aspx) blog has an [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_protocols/archive/2005/10/19/482840.aspx) that goes into some detail as to what the above code is doing.

Note:  If a firewall is blocking the port(s) you will still be unable to access the server via TCP.

Comment: @Rohit:  Glad to hear it helped though.

Comment: getting Invalid Namespace error when performing the sqlService.Get();
probably coming from the ServerProtocol section

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer\SuperSocketNetLib\Tcp` hive. There are keys like `Enabled`, `ListenOnAllIPs` and a list of IP addresses to listen on.